# Which Solr filter should I use to filter out fancy apostrophes

Tags: solr

## Problem

I'm using Apache SOLR for full-text search and right now I'm having trouble filtering out fancy apostrophes.

Users can enter queries and sometimes they use a 'typographic apostrophe' -- it's not a straight up-and-down apostrophe, it is slightly curled and slanted to the right like in this word:

**Plato’s Critique**

So, searching for the word like this

**Plato's Critique**

**Platos Critique**

yields no results, since ' and ’ are technically different characters.
But I want to get the record named "Plato’s Critique" back for any of these searches.

## Analyzer config options I've tried that haven't worked

I have tried a few different configuration options (and reindexed after making changes).

**Standard Filter factory**

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

**ICUFoldingFilter**

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ICUFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: You can use a PatternReplaceFilter if that's the only character you want to replace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing this up in case anyone else can benefit from this --
I had to apply the ICUFoldingFilterFactory to a textField that was an ngram. My change wasn't being taken in before because all of the textFields I wanted to search were ngrams.